# Is it possible to install an Apache module on a locked-down / shared server?

Tags: apache, server, installation

I'm new to Apache and I have a site hosted with ehosts.com. I'd like to use the Apache module [mod_auth_form](http://alessandro.melandri.net/using-apache-mod-auth-form/) to make an attractive web form login, rather than the unpleasant browser popup provided by basic authentication. However, as I'm on a shared server:

1. I don't have admin rights, so I can't install the module using, e.g. `sudo apt-get install`
2. I don't have access to the httpd.conf file so I can't load the module with e.g. `LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so`

Is there some way I can use an Apache module only for my site, within my restricted permissions? I can use .htaccess files to set directory properties that I can't set in my locked-down httpd.conf file, so I was wondering if there is a similar technique for requiring / providing modules?

Answer (score 0):

As you could see at the [LoadModule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) directive it could only execute in "server config" [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) which means: "It is not allowed in .htaccess files at all."